# ActiveX Spreadsheet MS access

Tags: ms-access, activexobject, xml-spreadsheet

I would like to ask your help please.

I'm trying to build a form where user will have the option to paste data on the form spreadsheet, after I want to recover that data by VBA to insert it on table.

how can I use that Active X spreadsheet ??
how can I know what value are on cell A1 for example ????

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set mySht = Me.Spreadsheet
```

With mySht
    With .ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet
        lastColumn = .UsedRange.Columns(mySht.ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
        lastrow = .Range("A" & mySht.ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
  End With

MsgBox "Table dimention, Lines = " & lastrow & " columns = " & lastColumn

ReDim linea(lastColumn)

For i = 1 To lastrow
        For j = 1 To lastColumn

```
    mySht.Cells(i, j) 'something with the cell (i, j)
Next ' end line
```

Next ' next Line
  ' dispose
Set mySht = Nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the object in a bound or unbound control:

```
Private Sub Command3_Click()
    Set obj = Me.OLEUnbound0.Object
    MsgBox obj.ActiveSheet.[a1]
End Sub
```

I think that it would be easier to just get the user to give you the name of the Excel sheet with the data. I suspect there will be quite a bit of training involved in this method.

Comment: Thank you very much for you interest.
I did it that way: see next